# What is the exception specification of std::function's move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've looked at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) and they seem to indicate no `noexcept` specification on `std::function(std::function&&)`. This seems rather odd to me. Does the standard really not give a nothrow guarantee in this case?

Comment: *// 20.8.11.2.1, construct/copy/destroy:
function() noexcept;
function(nullptr_t) noexcept;
function(const function&);
function(function&&);* - and the list goes on

Comment: @chris: The move constructor does indeed not have a `noexcept` specification, as the OP claims. What was the point of your comment?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I was referencing the standard. I've seen a couple of missing details on the site before, so it's always a good idea to go to the roots for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that the `function` object is capable of storing an arbitrary, user-defined, callable object. When you move the `function` object, that contained, user-defined object is moved as well, and there are no guarantees that this can be done without exceptions.

Comment: This seems likely, especially given the note at §20.8.11.2.1/5:  "Implementations are encouraged to avoid the use of dynamically
allocated memory for small callable objects, for example, where f’s target is an object holding only a
pointer or reference to an object and a member function pointer."

Comment: it may well be that the intent is to support callables that have throwing move constructors. but that is just *speculation*. for example, imagine reallocation of the buffer in a vector of such function objects, where an attempt is made to move the originals, and where in the middle somewhere one of them throws. oh dang, they can't guaranteed be moved back, and neither can we go forward. so the reallocation fails. a requirement of non-throwing *move* of the callable objects would have supported such general usage of function objects. which IMHO casts strong doubt on the assumption of intent.

Comment: For std::vector, if nothrow move construction cannot be guaranteed, a copy is made instead, as there is no other way to make the exception guarantees.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the standard (as you request):

> **C++11 §20.8.11.2.1/6** (from N3290):
>   `function(function&& f);`
>   `template <class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, function&& f);`
>   Effects: If `!f`, `*this` has no target; otherwise, move-constructs the target of `f` into the target of `*this`,
>   leaving `f` in a valid state with an unspecified value.

So, sorry, no `noexcept` on the move constructor.

There is a related [Defect Report 2062](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2062) which is still open, but it goes in the other direction, so to speak, namely that there is at least one `noexcept` that apparently should not be there, for whatever the rationale of that is…

It **may** be that the intent is to support callables that have throwing move constructors. But that is just speculation in the direction of rationalization. For example, imagine reallocation of the buffer in a vector of such function objects, where an attempt is made to move the originals, and where in the middle somewhere one of them throws (I think this was the original example by Abrahams et.al). Oh dang, they can't guaranteed be moved back, and neither can we go forward. So the reallocation fails, and the operation that caused the reallocation, fails, *with the vector in an invalid state*. A requirement of non-throwing move of the callable objects would have supported such general usage of function objects, including optimized vector reallocation (etc.). Which IMHO makes it doubtful that the intent really has been to make this trade-off.

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers really make sense to me.  `std::function` *does* have a `noexcept` default constructor and a `noexcept` `swap` method, so an implementor could always define the move constructor like so:

```
function(function&& other) noexcept
  : function()
{
  swap(*this, other);
}
```

Given the above, I'm not sure why the committee declined to make the move constructor `noexcept`.  In any case, you can work around the problem by creating a wrapper to hold the `std::function` and move it using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

As others said the `std::function` move constructor is **NOT** `noexcept` by the *C++* standard.

As *Peter Ruderman* said, an implementor can define `noexcept` move constructor using `swap` method (which is `noexcept` by the standard).

And the *GCC* implementation actually uses this technique and defines the `std::function` move constructor as `noexcept`:

```
/**
 *  @brief %Function move constructor.
 *  @param __x A %function object rvalue with identical call signature.
 *
 *  The newly-created %function contains the target of @a __x
 *  (if it has one).
 */
function(function&& __x) noexcept : _Function_base()
{
  __x.swap(*this);
}
```

So if you use *GCC*, you can assume that the `std::function` move constructor is `noexcept`. But other implementation of the *C++* standard library may have a different implementation of the move constructor. So you must not rely on that.

It is better to have `std::function` default constructed (`noexcept`) and then use `swap` method:

```
    // the line below could throw
    // std::function<void()> my_function(std::move(the_function_to_move_from));

    // the code below is noexcept
    std::function<void()> my_function;
    my_function.swap(the_function_to_move_from);
```

It is not as graceful as using move constructor but at least it is portable.

And beware of move semantic!!! It may do something you don't expect because it is usually specified to leave the object moved from in a valid but **unspecified** state. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    void call()
    {
        if (fn) fn();
    }

    std::function<void()> fn;
};

int main()
{
    std::function<void()> hello = []() { std::cerr << "Hello world" << std::endl; };
    A a;
    hello = std::move(a.fn);
    a.call(); // may print "Hello world". Is it what you expect?

    return 0;
}
```

The *GCC* implementation doesn't print *"Hello world"*, but other implementation may do. The right way is to explicitly clear the object moved from:

```
hello = std::move(a.fn);
a.fn = nullptr;
```

But it makes move semantic inconvenient to use (IMO).